# Update all rows where contains 5 keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have `Ticket` table that has some columns like this  :

```
ID : int
Body : nvarchar
Type : int
```

I have many rows where the `Body` column has value like this :

```
IPAddress = sometext, ComputerName = sometext , GetID =  sometext, CustomerName=sometext-sometext , PharmacyCode = 13162900
```

I want update all rows' `Type` column where the `Body` column has at least five of the following keys:

```
IPAddress, ComputerName, GetID, CustomerName, PharmacyCode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a simple update statement like that

```
UPDATE Ticket
SET Type = 4
WHERE Body LIKE '%IPAddress%'
  and Body LIKE '%ComputerName%' 
  and Body LIKE '%GetID%' 
  and Body LIKE '%CustomerName%' 
  and Body LIKE '%PharmacyCode%'
```

if you know the 'keys' are always in the same order you could concatenate the `LIKE` conditions like so

```
UPDATE Ticket
SET Type = 4
WHERE Body LIKE '%IPAddress%ComputerName%GetID%CustomerName%PharmacyCode%'
```

If you have the possibility to change the data model it would be much better to explode this key & value column into an own table and link it back to this table as it is done in a proper relational model.

Answer (score 1):

If you could calculate number of key value pair by number of `=` present in your string you could use this query

```
Update tblname set col=val where   len(colname) - len(replace(colname,'=','')>5
```

The where part actually gives number of equal signs present in your string.